# argumentList only show one

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I've tried the following code but only the first of `otherButtonTitles` shows up.

```
- (id)initWithCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle primaryButtonTitle:(NSString *)primaryButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        // Build normal buttons
        va_list argumentList;
        va_start(argumentList, otherButtonTitles);

        NSString *argString = otherButtonTitles;

        while (argString != nil)
        {
            UIButton *button = [self buildButtonWithTitle:argString];

            [self.buttons addObject:button];

            argString = va_arg(argumentList, NSString *);
        }

        va_end(argumentList);

        // Build cancel button
        UIButton *cancelButton = [self buildCancelButtonWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle];
        [self.buttons insertObject:cancelButton atIndex:0];

        // Add primary button
        if (primaryButtonTitle)
        {
            UIButton *primaryButton = [self buildPrimaryButtonWithTitle:primaryButtonTitle];
            [self.buttons addObject:primaryButton];
        }

        // Add destroy button
        if (destructiveButtonTitle)
        {
            UIButton *destroyButton = [self buildDestroyButtonWithTitle:destructiveButtonTitle];
            [self.buttons insertObject:destroyButton atIndex:1];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

How to modify it?

Comment: If you create function more than 2-3 argument, i recommend you create one dictionary as a argument of that methods and your previous argument should be member of that dictionary. So your code will be easy to read and well maintained

Comment: i want to know my code why only give first .thank you for your answer

Comment: :D i'm not yet answering. I just give you suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my general template I've written for you. it is working like a charm with various number of arguments. I think It can help you to solve your problem easily:

**.h** file

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithDictionaries:(NSDictionary *)dictionary, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

**.m** file

```
- (NSMutableArray *)arrayWithDictionaries:(NSDictionary *)dictionary, ... {
    NSMutableArray *_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // I'm building the array of the arguments
    va_list _arguments;
    va_start(_arguments, dictionary);

    for (NSDictionary *_currentArgument = dictionary; _currentArgument != nil; _currentArgument = va_arg(_arguments, NSDictionary*)) {
        [_array addObject:_currentArgument];
    }

    va_end(_arguments);

    return _array;
}
```

---

**UPDATE#1** *(on 090413)*

here is your code... ...

**.h** file

```
- (id)initWithCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle primaryButtonTitle:(NSString *)primaryButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

**.m** file

```
- (id)initWithCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle primaryButtonTitle:(NSString *)primaryButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        // Build normal buttons
        va_list _arguments;
        va_start(_arguments, otherButtonTitles);

        for (NSString *_currentArgument = otherButtonTitles; _currentArgument != nil; _currentArgument = va_arg(_arguments, NSString*)) {
             UIButton *button = [self buildButtonWithTitle:_currentArgument];
             [self.buttons addObject:button];
        }

        va_end(_arguments);

        // Build cancel button
        UIButton *cancelButton = [self buildCancelButtonWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle];
        [self.buttons insertObject:cancelButton atIndex:0];

        // Add primary button
        if (primaryButtonTitle)
        {
            UIButton *primaryButton = [self buildPrimaryButtonWithTitle:primaryButtonTitle];
            [self.buttons addObject:primaryButton];
        }

        // Add destroy button
        if (destructiveButtonTitle)
        {
            UIButton *destroyButton = [self buildDestroyButtonWithTitle:destructiveButtonTitle];
            [self.buttons insertObject:destroyButton atIndex:1];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

---

**UPDATE#2** *(on 090413)*

you should call the method like this:

```
[[... alloc] initWithCancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Title" primaryButtonTitle:@"Primary Title" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive Title" otherButtonTitles:@"Other Title 1", @"Other Title 2", @"Other Title 3", nil];
```

Comment: how to use the methods for my method?

Comment: you don't look to expert to implement a feature, huh? but no worries, I've done it for you, check my updated answer...

Comment: thank you ,i will check it tomorrow.

Comment: i think your method using for  is the same as my while?what is the different?

Comment: the possible difference is my code is working with various number of arguments like a charm.